# Spring MVC Tomcat Disable JSESSIONID

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, httpsession, jsessionid

I have a WebApp with Spring MVC , I run it on the web with Tomcat 7 server . On my localhost Tomcat 9 server my WebApp works just fine creating a session due to a class I created .

In each method in my controller and I have there 5 methods most of them ModelAndView methods e.g :

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/home" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView goHomePage(HttpSession session, @PathVariable String,HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap modelMap) {

.... return ModelAndView object;

}
```

I have a user check method that checks if user is on the DataBase and in this method I add Session ID to go with each method until session is over.

```
RequestMapping(value = "/check", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String check(HttpServletRequest request,User user,BindingResult bindingResult){

request.getSession().setAttribute("sessionId", id);
return "redirect:/home";
}
```

and in all other methods It takes each time an HttpSession obect as parameter and checks if it contains the attribute "sessionId".

On my LocalHost it works fine , on my webserver it works fine when I use myhostname.com:8080/WAR_FILE_NAME , but when I use the normal way it adds to my URL line some JSESSIONID=123456 number and doesn't give me to go to the other pages the WebApp has .

Could somebody explain why it happend and what can I do to fix it or disable this jsession cause I use my own session tracking .

I checked already here some answers for common cases but non of them works for me .

Comment: You can disable URL rewrite in context config - http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html

Comment: Couldnt understand exactly what I should write ?!

Comment: Update `Context` element in Tomcat's `config/context.xml` by adding attribute `disableURLRewriting="true"`.